# How to safetly export all IIS settings from one server to another?

Tags: iis, configuration, system-administration, metabase

I am trying to build a virtual machine that clones one of the servers used in production instances of our webapp so that we can do deployment testing on it.

I have gotten all the necessary files over, IIS installed, the database up and running.  To my eye all that remains is to copy all the IIS settings from a production environment to the virtual machine.  In the past I have in similar situations simply backed up the metabase, found the file, moved it to the new machine, and restored.  This is a more difficult scenario however and when I try to do this the target machine tells me the metabase file has "invalid signature".

Googling around for a while I find the the recommendation for this is to use iiscnfg.vbs /export however, the msdn page on [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/73f66ff1-be38-4850-8965-739004acd641.mspx?mfr=true) recommends using [iiscnfg.vbs /copy](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/81f04967-f02f-4845-9795-bad2fe1a1687.mspx?mfr=true) (though the link points to itself).

So following all the steps for copy, I get the following output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cscript.exe iiscnfg.vbs /copy /ts 208.10.202.61 /tu wmydomain\admin /tp mypassword
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.

Backing up server 127.0.0.1
Backup complete.
Mapping local drive E: to admin share on server 127.0.0.1
Mapping local drive F: to admin share on server 208.10.202.61
```

Which looks good, except that on the target computer it would seem that nothing has changed.  What gives?  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/445/synchronize-iis-60/) to sync websites between a local and remote IIS server. (It also works to go to IIS 7 from IIS 6)

Comment: hmmm...these servers actually were both on .NET 1.1 so it wouldn't have worked (2.0 is a prereq).  However by the time I had gotten this response I had already gone through each setting and made it identical by hand.  Slow, but it works

Answer (score 1):

There are many utilities which allow you to create virtual machines from running servers.  For example here is the one from VMWare (http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/).  Easiest way I have found for virtualizing physical machines.

If you are going to run in on the same network/domain, you will need to change the sid of the machine.  If I remember correctly, the application will do it for you.  It is definitely worth checking out.